# Trouble configuring springdoc-openapi with Spring Boot 3.2.2

Tags: maven, openapi, java-17, springdoc-openapi-ui, spring-boot-3

I am working on a Spring Boot project which has Rest APIs. It's a backend project.

I am configuring OpenAP I3.0 as per the documentation here https://springdoc.org/#Introduction

I have included this dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using maven to build the project. It downloads necessary jars, then I started the application but when I am accessing this link `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`

I am getting this:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> No static resource swagger-ui/index.html.
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource swagger-ui/index.html.`

I tried to use these properties inside my `application.yml` but the result is still same.

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
    path: /v3/api-docs
```

I do not understand why this is not working because as per documentation it should work once we have added dependency and build the project.

Note: I do not have any configuration class yet. Just a RestController and Service Class. And, as of now I am not using spring-security. I am using springboot-maven-plugin.

Also one strange thing which I noticed that when the application `jar` file is created, there is no `resource` folder inside `META-INF`. Maybe it is looking for index.html inside that resource folder and that is causing the issue but I am not sure.

Comment: You set **/swagger-ui.html** in **springdoc.swagger-ui/path** property, but you are trying to access **/swagger-ui/index.html** . Are you sure it is not just a typo issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Spring boot 3.2 and `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui 1.8.0`.
It seems like the problem is related to some conflict version with spring boot.

In my case, I changed the Spring doc dependency to `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.4.0`, after it worked fine.

Be sure to allow the necessary URL in the security configuration.

Answer (score -1):

got the same error

```
14-03-2024 12:51:15.483 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler | Resource not found
14-03-2024 12:51:15.483 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver | Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource swagger-ui/index.html.]
14-03-2024 12:51:15.484 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor | Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
14-03-2024 12:51:15.484 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet | Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

it's remarkable that I have another project that works, searching for a solution

Comment: Going to spring boot 3.2.3 swagger didn't work until I put the following dependency, org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:5.10.3, the default one, org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:5.11.8 didn't work. Got a 404 every time. Found the version by comparing the dependency:tree of 3.2.2 that worked fine with dependency:tree of 3.2.3 that didn't work

Comment: please add a comment on the main question, as this "answer" isn't an answer